# Convert Dynamic Web Project to Maven = deployment empty

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, maven

I have a Dynamic Web Project, that is deployed to a Tomcat server by Run As > on Server. The Project has WebServices WSDL, which work fine this way.

But I want to convert to maven/pom. So I use eclipse and choose "convert project to maven".
Afterwards, when I again choose > Run on Server, the tomcat deploy dir is empty!
What is changing exactly when converting to maven project, and how can I fix the deployment process again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be to use the Maven Tomcat plugin:

http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html

This way, you can create a Maven Run Configuration in Eclipse that compiles and deploys your app to Tomcat with one button click. There is also a Jetty server plugin.